Restricting Typescript class property to child of a class
Can I restrict the Data property to the child classes of Filter for any class that is a child of UIFilterControl? So when I create a new class that extends UIFilterControl the Data property on the new class would need to be a child class of Filter.
+ UIFilterControl
| * Data
|
|-- UIControlRangeSlide
|   * Data: FilterRange        <--- valid property class defined.
|-- UIControlSearchSelector
|   * Data: FilterSet          <--- valid property class defined.
|-- UIControlRangeSlide
|   * Data: ContainerClass     <--- not valid

Filter and it's child classes:
+ Filter
|- FilterRange
|- FilterSet
|- FilterValue


Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't the "Not valid" line be written to say Data: Filter     <--- Not valid ? Or else maybe that variant would be useful to add?

Please don’t repost the same question

@PeterB no, the Data property class can be any child class of Filter

@DanielA.White It's not the same, I've changed what I was asking

Instead of what looks like a diagram, could you please provide a [mre] we can copy into an IDE to get to work on it? Otherwise we all have to create the definitions for your classes ourselves and we might all do it differently.

I don't think you need any code, I'm asking if there's a language feature to do something. Code isn't going to help.

In my experience on Stack Overflow, questions with a [mre] are much more likely to get good answers than those without. Pragmatically speaking, code definitely helps. (And if it matters, I have not downvoted this question)

@PeterB oh you're right, probably only noticed that now because I had a coffee

Not sure if I was able to fully understand your question but if you have filters like this:
class Filter {
  someBaseProp: any;
}
class FilterRange extends Filter {
  range: any;
}
class FilterSet extends Filter {
  set: any;
}
class FilterValue extends Filter {
  value: any;
}

And something that is not a Filter;
class ContainerClass { // <-- Not a Filter

}

To make sure that UIFilterControl has a property called data and value as a Filter you can use a generic constraint:
class UIFilterControl<T extends Filter> { // <-- constraint
  constructor(public data: T){}
}

You will then not be able to create UIFilterControl child classes that don't use a filter;
class UIControlRangeSlide extends UIFilterControl<FilterRange> { // OK
  doSomething() {
    type test = typeof this.data; // FilterRange
  }
}

class UIControlSearchSelector extends UIFilterControl<FilterSet> { // OK
  doSomething() {
    type test = typeof this.data; // FilterSet
  }
}

class UIControlRangeSlide2 extends UIFilterControl<ContainerClass> { // ERROR
  doSomething() {
    type test = typeof this.data; // ContainerClass
  }
}

I hope that this is what you are looking for.

gosh, just made a coffee and opened the browser to find this answer, typescript does it nicely too.
